# Show that as rings $\Bbb Z_{mn} \ncong \Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n$ if $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

So I just got done showing explicitly that an isomorphism exists between these two rings if the $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, and I did not have much trouble with that. For some reason I'm having a lot harder of a time showing that the result *is not* true if $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime. Can somebody help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm a little worried about whether your proof that they are isometric when coprime is complete.  You should have needed the fact they were coprime thus giving you the idea of why they wouldn't be if the were not coprime.

Comment: To prove that $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ I assume you did something like show that $mn*(1,1) = (0,0)$ so $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n = <(1,1)>$ which is the cyclic group of order $mn$.  But did you prove that $k(1,1) \ne (0,0)$ for *any* $k < mn$?

Answer (score 5):

If $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime then they have a least common multiple $L$ which is *less* than $mn$. (Namely $\frac {mn}{\gcd(n,m)}$)

And if you take any element of $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z_m\times \mathbb Z_n$ and add it to itself $L$ times  you get the identity[1].  So there is no element with order $mn$.  So it can not be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ as $1\in \mathbb Z_{mn}$ has order $mn$.

.....

[1] If $a \in \mathbb Z_m$ then $(km)*a = 0$ for all integers $k$ and if $b \in \mathbb Z_n$ then $(kn)*b = 0$ for all integers $k$.  So if $k = L = m*\frac n{\gcd(n,m)} = n*\frac m{\gcd(m,n)}$ then $L*(a,b) = (0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Show that $\mbox{lcm} (m,n) \cdot (x,y) =(0,0)$ for all elements $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$.